# Validation with $email does an mysql_syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

i have the following code:

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE member_regok SET newmemberid = '.$last_id.', status = 1 WHERE email = '".$email."'");
```

This code returns "syntax error after "@email.com" ". I can return all these $var with echo and I get the result but running this query doe not work. Is there a problem with validating with $email?

Comment: Can you do `echo` instead of `mysql_query` so we can see what is being sent to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE member_regok SET newmemberid = '$last_id', status = '1' WHERE email = '$email'");
```